# Prove that any monotonic and bijective function is an homeomorphism with the usual topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:(\mathbb{R},d_u)\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R},d_u)$ an arbitrary function.

Where $d_u$ is the usual distance.

I have an exercise in which, with the sole asumptions of it being monotonic (increasing, in particular) and surjective, I have to prove it is an homeomorphism.

Is this exercise even properly formulated? Since its monotonic, it is injective and hence bijective. But, how about the continuity, can we assure $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous?

(Actually, the exercise doesn't mention that it is strictly increasing, it just says increasing, but I have assumed it means strictly increasing or else the function wouldn't even necessarily need to be injective).

Comment: Regarding the parenthetical remark: there are different conventions. Some say increasing only for strictly increasing functions and use non-decreasing for not-necessarily-strictly increasing functions. That seems to be the case here. To the meat of the question: The point is to show that a surjective monotonic function is necessarily continuous. (Then, since the inverse is also monotonic ...) The reason is that a monotonic function can have only jump discontinuities if any, and if it had a jump, it would not be surjective.

Comment: Ohh, I see, thanks for the clarification @Daniel ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right, it has to be strictly increasing, otherwise a counterexample is easy to find. an increasing function can only have discontinuities of the kind $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a-} = f(a) - c$$ for some $c > 0$. these are called jump discontinuites. if this is the case at some $a$ then $f$ can't take values from the interval $(a-c, a)$ because of its monotonicity and since we assume $f$ to be surjective this is a contradiction, hence $f$ is continuous. $f^{-1}$ exists since $f$ is bijective, to show that it's continuous just note that if $f$ is increasing then $f^{-1}$ is decreasing and repeat the reasoning (or apply what you've done to $-f^{-1}$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mm-aops, you and Daniel have really helped me out to understand this ;)